# PHPExcel how to generate excel file via controller of Laravel 5

Tags: excel, laravel-5, controller, phpexcel

I use the library PHPExcel included in `Classes` directory. 
I do a simple test in my controller.
In my controller, i placed this code:

```
    `include(app_path().'/Classes/PHPExcel.php');`
    `include(app_path().'/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php');`
```

Then I instantiate the object PHPExcel :

```
    `$workbook = new PHPExcel;`
```

I activate the sheet on which I work (the default form),  with method `->getActiveSheet()`.

```
    `$sheet = $workbook->getActiveSheet();`
```

I filled my first cell with the method `->setCellValue()`.

```
    `$sheet->setCellValue('A1','MaitrePylos');`
```

Finally to create the file, I need to instantiate an object writer, specific to the type of picture I want to generate.

```
    `$writer = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($workbook);`
```

I give a name to my file, and save :

```
    `$records = 'storage/app/sampleData/fichier.xlsx';`
    `$writer->save($records);`
```

Result: I have a generated error
        `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007' not found`

Who can help me to better organize my code and fix my error problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Laravel Excel Package, behind the scenes it uses the PHPExcel class.

https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

Comment: I prefried PHPExcel use the library because the examples are numerous and well detailed. Too, i can generate PDF documents

Comment: In that case, you don't need to `include` classes in your Controller.

PHPExcel supports composer. So all you need to do is, ru the following command: `composer require phpoffice/phpexcel`.

You might also need to update your composer.json file and add the following lines into `autoload` section: 

`"psr-0": {
            "PHPExcel": "Classes/"
        }`